# MySQL Can't connect to server on localhost with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm using XAMPP 1.7.2 and can connect to MySQL via cmd and SQLYog, but not programmatically.

This PHP code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '*****');
    if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());
}
```

gives me:

```
mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10013) in C:\test\login.php on line 10
Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10013)
```

How do I debug this issue?

Comment: Where is the code that tries to connect?

Comment: edited the question to add the database connection code

Comment: try defining the port... localhost:10013

Comment: By default root doesn't have a password and you have to start MySQL server separately.

Comment: @phpmeh can you please elaborate on "try defining the port"

Comment: @PhpXp That is not true at all. Not sure where you get that information. it is up to who every did the installation and how the server is setup. By default, during installation it will prompt you to enter password for root.

Comment: I recently installed MySQL on Windows 7. What is your OS? Did you get this problem fixed yet?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid yes this problem got fixed, please read my comments below on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753285/mysql-cant-connect-to-sever-on-localhost-via-php-script#comment12741167_9753498 BTW I am using win7 OS

Answer (score 0):

Your connection shows an Error #10013. It's basically a firewall problem or socket error. Maybe your mysql setup is not on default port? (which is 3306)

Comment: its on default port (which is 3306)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a hint to your problem. Not sure if it is. In the following post, i read that there maybe your firewall that preventing your connection. Try disabling your firewall and see if u can connect. If you can, then configure your firewall differently.

Reference
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,152798

Comment: Have you try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: yes I had tried with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, I had also tried with different host name via drivers/etc/hosts file

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally 127.0.0.1 will work instead of localhost. Same location, just a different reference to it.

A basic thing to check is that all the login credentials are correct. Have the right user/pass/dbName?

Comment: yep, user/pass/dbname are correct and I am able to access that database via cmd using the same credentials

Comment: okay I have figured it out... sorry for posting it late... It was due to one of mysql service was running in background..I had installed xampp before removing previous mysql instances. I removed all instances of mysql from my machine and then installed the XAMPP and it works absolutely fine now :)